# Documenting front end

Tags: frontend, web-frontend

so I got a job interview and part of it is passing a test which consists of programming a front-end of a web page from a PSD mockup. In any case, employer said I will have 3 hours time to submit a solution (i.e. html/css/js of the web page created from the mockup) and additional hour to submit *documentation*.
So I have a question for those of you more well versed in the subject at hand.
What does front-end *documentation* consist of? I've never heard of such a thing... I mean it is also possible they just used this particular term for me to write some mundane description idk.

Comment: What if your future employer just wants to test whether you are a person who asks back in case of uncertainty rather than just doing something?

Comment: This thought has crossed my mind as well :)

Comment: i would assume it relates to, how the page will break down being responsive and why it breaks down how it does, what you could do to reduce the load time of the page - if there are any post compression needed. Where specific files are located for different things, i could image you could write up lots on that.